# Difference between cir.radius and (cir.radius)

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
struct circle {  
int center;  
int radius;  
};  
struct circle *cir;

cir.center  
cir->radius  
(cir.radius)  
(cir->center)
```

what is the difference between this 4 last lines? I know that cir.center is accessing a member of a struct circle pointed to by a variable cir. cir->radius is the same but pointed to by a pointer variable cir. But what do the () do?

Comment: Parenthesis don't do anything alone. They might make difference when used in larger expression. Please provide complete statement.

Comment: One difference is that `cir.center` does not compile because `cir` is a pointer.

Comment: I believe this is what you want to know: `(*cir).radius` is same as `cir->radius`

Comment: What did your beginner level C book say about this when you read about structs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `cir` is declare as a pointer to the structure i.e.**`struct circle *cir;`** you have to use **`->`** operator to **access the elements of a structure**

if `cir` is only declare as a variable of the type structure i.e. **`struct circle cir;`** then you have to use **`.`** operator to **access the elements of structure**

as `()` does not make any difference here so **`(cir.radius) = cir.radius` and `(cir->center)=cir->center`**

Comment: If that is a answer of  your question you can accept it by clicking on tick near to the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

`cir.center` - Access `center` inside struct if `cir` wasn't a pointer
`cir->radius` - Dereference `cir` and then access `radius` 
`(cir.radius)` - Same as `cir.center` if `cir` wasn't a pointer
`(cir->center)` - Dereference `cir` and access `center`

Notice the difference without pointer:

```
struct circle {  
    int center;  
    int radius;  
};
...
circle cir;
cir.center = 5;
printf("%d", cir.center);
//              ^
```

And pointer

```
circle* cir;
...
cir->radius = 5;
// ^^
```

Another way of writing `cir->radius` is `(*cir).radius`

Answer (score 0):

See the below stuff :

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct circle
{
    int r;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct circle obj;
    struct circle* obj1=&obj;

    printf("Enter radius : ");
    scanf("%d",&obj.r); 
    /* here membership operator '.' has precedence over '&'
     * consider obj.r as a variable x, then normal scanf procdedure
     * applies that is you're accessing the memory using &x
     */
    printf("Entered radius : %d\n",obj.r);
    /* For printf we don't need the '&' */

    printf("Enter radius : ");
    scanf("%d",&(*obj1).r);
    /* Now things have become really dirty
     * First we need to use the dereference operator on obj1 which is a
     * pointer to structure and then
     * user the membership operator '.' to access the variable
     * The reference operator '& above here has the least preference
     * it gives the address of the chunk of memory dedicated to 'r'
     */

    printf("Entered radius : %d\n",(*obj1).r);


    printf("Enter radius : ");
    scanf("%d",&obj1->r);

    /* Well, here the 'obj1->' replaces the '(*obj1).' and 
     * both have the same meaning.
     * The -> is called the indirection operator which makes things
     * look neater. Note that you still need the reference operator
     * '&' for the structure member 'r'
     */

    printf("Entered radius : %d\n",obj1->r);
    return 0;
}
```

Above are the valid stuff and you can indeed use parenthesis to make things even more clearer in your code.